# Como criar aplicativos Android em PC fraco?

Tags: android, android-studio, eclipse

Eu tenho um notebook com um processador de 1,3Ghz e 4 GB de RAM.

Ele é bom, porém sempre que tento criar um aplicativo para Android me deparo com *lag*, lentidão, travamentos, etc...

Eu tenho no meu notebook o Android Studio e o Eclipse Android Neon.

Tem alguma forma de criar um aplicativo Android com uma IDE mais leve, e que tenha um criador de layout das *activities* bem levinho?
Assim eu poderia começar a estudar mais o Android, esse é meu único obstáculo.

Comment: Você deveria analisar o por quê de estar com essa lentidão, se é CPU, RAM, disco, ou software mesmo. De qualquer forma, vale notar que IDEs são tradicionalmente muito mais pesadas e violam o princípio "Do One Thing and Do It Well", fazendo com que muitos prefiram usar editores de texto para programar. Dê uma olhada no [eclim (vim + funcionalidades do eclipse)](http://eclim.org/) e sublimetext

Comment: obrigado amigo, mas eu sempre rodei eclipse de boa, mas só essas ide de android que trava mesmo

Comment: @SampaioLeal Seu problema muito provavelmente é RAM e não CPU. Quanto de RAM você tem? Ir para um sistema operacional mais leve (caso você use Windows) também ajuda.

Comment: @PabloAlmeida 4Gb cara, mas to com muitos problemas aqui mano, Internet, Plugins desatualizados, e o Android Studio sumiu, eu ein, deu ate erro de 64 bits no executavel! dentro da pasta bin do Studio

Comment: Mesmo minha máquina i5 tinha problemas em rodar o Android Studio com 4 GB de RAM, e mesmo no Linux. Te recomendo no mínimo 6 GB de RAM e, de preferência, 8 GB se quer trabalhar com Android. Processador não faz tanta diferença assim ao ponto de ser um problema.

Comment: vlw, mas acho que vo é desistir affs, meu eclipse cheio de bugs em relação ao Android,

Comment: @SampaioLeal Mas por que você tá usando Eclipse?

Comment: Porque o Android Studio (o executável) sumiu, e ele travava muito, principalmente na hora da edição de layout, na hora de abrir outros arquivos, quase tudo clicável travava!

Comment: @SampaioLeal Coloque mais 2 ou 4 GB de RAM e tente de novo com o Android Studio (baixe de novo, se sumiu). O Eclipse não tem mais suporte pra desenvolvimento Android. Não faz sentido considerá-lo.

Comment: Bom, eu uso notebook ASUS, e nem sei se daria muito certo!

Comment: O meu é ASUS também. Coloquei mais 4 GB de RAM nele e tá muito bem.

Comment: Como fizestes isso?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Experimente o [IntelliJ IDEA](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/), ele conta com um editor de layout também: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/designer-tool-window.html

Comment: muito obrigado amigão, acho que este é o que mais se encaixa com meu note, obrigado mesmo, já faço o download e começo a programar hehe

Comment: uma mini-dúvida, qual a melhor opção para download?

Comment: Se usar o Intellij no ubuntu fica bem mais leve do que no windows. Você pode usar a versão Community que é free..

Comment: A Ultimate é paga e custa tipo 300 dólares (mas tem trial de 30 dias), a Community é de graça. Eu baixaria a Ultimate pra sentir o gostinho, no entanto como você tá preocupado com desempenho, a Community pode ser melhor porque tem menos recursos – logo é mais leve.

Comment: @rodorgas para android, não tem diferença entre a versão Community e Ultimate, a Ultimate tem mais recursos para JAVA EE mesmo, o Android Studio é baseado na versão Community..

Answer (score 3):

Você pode tentar usar o IntelXDK, ele é bem mais leve...

Comment: mas ele tem o editor de layout?

Comment: tipo, quando eu tento rodar o app trava tudo aki

Comment: sim, ele é uma alternativa ao Android Studio e ao Eclipse, porem ele não trabalha com java... só com HTML 5, CSS e javaScript

Comment: huuum, me parece bom, porem, estou usando a net do vizinho, acho que vou fazer umas gambiarras e fazer esse android studio rodar